# Using esc_url with a hard coded url

Tags: theme-development, themes, security

I've added following URL in my theme, but I have been informed that I must use `esc_url()`. I could not figure out, how can I use that function with following code?

```
<a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=<?php echo urlencode( get_the_permalink() ); ?>&amp;media=<?php echo urlencode($thumbnail); ?>&amp;description=<?php echo urlencode( get_the_title() ); ?>" target="_blank">Pinterest</a>
```

Comment: doesn't look like you need esc_url or even the urlencode you use except for the title portion

Comment: I thought so too, but a theme reviewer insists :$

Comment: I you think you need it. You are using the title in a URL and you are getting the title dinamically; so you never know exactly if the title is URL-econded or not. Better to use it. Just one example: it is very common that titles contain [white spaces and white spaces need to be enconded to be used in URLs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442658/spaces-in-urls).

Comment: @cybmeta can you give an example how can i use that function with above url?

Comment: Sure, see answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I you think you need it. For example, you are using the title in a URL and you are getting the title dinamically; so you never know exactly if the title is valid to be used in URL or not. So, it is better to use it.

Just one example: it is very common that titles contain [white spaces and white spaces need to be enconded to be used in URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442658/spaces-in-urls).

I would build the full URL string first and then I would use `esc_url()` at moment it is used for some attribute value.

```
$url_params = array(
    'url'         => get_the_permalink(),
    'media'       => $thumbnail,
    'description' => get_the_title()
);

$url = "http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?" . http_build_query( $url_params );

echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $url ) . '">Pinterest</a>';
```